# Почему стили кнопки в android studio не применяются?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/startLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/on_off"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/start"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

on_off.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_off"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_on"/>
</selector>
```

btn_on.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="15dp" android:color="@color/white"/>
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>
<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

btn_off.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:width="15dp" android:color="@color/black"/>
<solid android:color="@color/white"/>
<corners android:radius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Вроде бы всё верно. Как вы определили, что они не применяются?

Comment: Вы именно в дизайнере AS не видите эти стили или все-таки в запущенном приложении?

Comment: Думаю, что стили применяются, но возможно вы просто не получили результат который хотели.